# Manage Browser Cookie Editing for web application in .Net Mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working with sensitive web application developing with .net mvc and I am Saving my user credentials after login with cookies .

The issue is, one user can able to login with their user name and password .Then he/She can able to edit the cookies and reset cookies to another user id .It's leading to security issue .How can we prevent that ?

Comment: You should NEVER store security sensitive data (such as user credentials) in cookies.Cookies are not secure at all.

Comment: Question should be asked in https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

How about using sessions instead?

For example you have a UserInfo class and an instance say userInfo having properties such as Username and other user values you need to store, you can store it session using the following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUserInfo"] = userInfo;
```

To fetch the stored values, use the following:

```
UserInfo userInfo = HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUserInfo"] as UserInfo;
```

To remove the session variable, use the following:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("CurrentUserInfo");
```

Comment: You have enough rep to post comments instead of link only answers.

Comment: Thanks @Steve for pointing that out. New in StackOverflow. Anyway, answer has been edited.